# Laravel Backpack create CRUD with model A but populate it with model B on add

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

I want to make a clone of an entity (let's say a Plan) - and add a FuturePlan.
So when I click on a Plan - "Add future plan" I want to open the FuturePlan form but pre-populated with the plan details.

I have the CRUD backpack working for Plan entity.
I also have the CRUD backpack for FuturePlan.
They extend the same baseClass so they have the same fields - only the crud->model is different.

```
PHP 7.1
Laravel 5.5 
backpack/generators 1.1.13
backpack/base 0.8.3
backpack/crud 3.3.2
```

The problem seems to be that if I declare the crud->model as FuturePlan, it won't know how to fill the form fields with the defaults?

Anyone any idea how to do this please?

Answer (score 1):

You can pre-populate Backpack fields by using the `default` or `value` attributes on fields. So if you send a GET or POST request towards the Create form, you can do something like this:

```php
public function setupCreateOperation() 
{
    CRUD::field('name')->default(request()->input('name') ?? null);
}
```

Alternatively, if you prefer the array syntax for fields, it would be:

```php
public function setupCreateOperation() 
{
    CRUD::addField([
        'name' => 'name',
        'type' => 'text',
        'label' => 'Name',
        'default' => request()->input('name') ?? null,
    ]);
}
```